# Trigonometric number theory

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> Suppose $\tan \alpha = \dfrac{p}{q}$, where $p$ and $q$ are integers and $q \neq 0$. Prove that the number $\tan \beta$ for which $\tan {2 \beta} = \tan {3 \alpha}$ is rational only when $p^2 + q^2$ is the square of an integer.

The solution below doesn't seem to make sense since it seems to say that $2\beta = 3\alpha$, which isn't necessarily true by the problem statement. I am wondering then how they can say the first claim they make.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the condition $2\gamma=\alpha$ in the second line is redundant. 
Maybe the following is more convincible.

Let $\gamma=\beta-\alpha$, then $\tan\beta$ is rational if and only if $\tan\gamma$ is rational. Moreover, we have
\begin{align}
\tan 2\gamma&=\tan(2\beta-2\alpha)\\
&=\frac{\tan2\beta-\tan2\alpha}{1+\tan2\beta\cdot\tan2\alpha}\\
&=\frac{\tan3\alpha-\tan2\alpha}{1+\tan3\alpha\cdot\tan2\alpha}\\
&=\tan(3\alpha-2\alpha)\\
&=\tan\alpha.
\end{align}
Therefore the result follows by the original proof.

Comment: Also, isn't is wrong to put $2\gamma = \alpha$? since it implies that $2\beta = 3\alpha$.

Comment: Our goal is $\tan 2\gamma=\tan\alpha$, not $2\gamma=\alpha$. So I think the solution has a little logical defect.

Comment: Also, $2\gamma=\alpha$ iff $3\beta=2\alpha$, where the second equality  cannot be obtained from the given condition.